# extremely simple haskell program but i still have problems finding my errors

Tags: list, haskell

```
andX :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
andX []         []      = []  
andX [xs]       []      = [xs]  
andX []         [ys]    = [ys]  
andX [x:xs] [y:ys]  = [x,y] : andX [xs] [ys]
```

Hi guys this is a very simple code I wrote and I think what it should do is clear but it just doesnt work and i cant seem to find a way to fix it.
I am grateful for every help get but please correct the program as is because for now I am not looking to find another way to write the same program but to find the errors i already created 
thanks in advance

Comment: Your pattern matching doesn't mean what you think.  `[x:xs]` is a list of one element, that element is itself a list with at least one element `x` followed by the rest of the list `xs`.  What you probably want is `(x:xs)` and same with `(y:ys)`.

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand something of my answer

Answer (score 8):

There are some problems here, but the most important is probably that the **list syntax** is wrong.

There are two types of list *constructors*:

1. the empty list `[]`; and
2. the *cons* `(x:xs)` (note round brackets).

Your first clause is thus correct: you match two *empty* lists.

The second and third are *syntactically* correct, but it means that you match a **singleton** list: a list with one item. This is because Haskell has syntactical sugar: `[x]` is short for `(x:[])`. I'm quite certain you do not want to match a singleton list, but any list. In case you want to do that, you can simply write:

```
andX xs [] = ...
andX [] ys = ...
```

but now there will be other problems which we will discuss later.

The last clause is an example of using *cons* for both parameters. So you should write it as:

```
andX (x:xs) (y:ys)  = [x,y] : andX xs ys
```

Note that we do not write `andX [xs] [ys]` in the recursive calls (since that would result in constructing singelton lists), but we pass the *tails* of both the first and second list.

So now we obtain:

```
andX :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
andX []     []     = []  
andX xs     []     = xs
andX []     ys     = ys
andX (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x,y] : andX xs ys
```

But it is still incorrect. There are basically two applications I can think of.

## "merging" the two lists

If you want to merge the lists in the sense that we obtain a list of the form:

```
[x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,...]
```

then we can not write the inductive case as:

```
andX (x:xs) (y:ys)  = [x,y] : andX xs ys
```

since here as return we take `[x,y]` as *one* first element of the output. We can however write:

```
andX (x:xs) (y:ys)  = x : y : andX xs ys
```

now we emit the two items `x` and `y` as separate items, followed by the recursive call. In that case the code fragment is:

```
andX :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
andX []     []     = []  
andX xs     []     = xs
andX []     ys     = ys
andX (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : andX xs ys
```

**Example**:

```
Prelude> andX [1,4,2,5] [1,3,0,2,5]
[1,1,4,3,2,0,5,2,5]
```

## Constructing sublists

Based on your code you want to returns a list of lists. But your output type says `[a]`. If you want to return a list of lists, it should be `[[a]]`.

```
andX :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
andX []     []     = []  
andX xs     []     = xs
andX []     ys     = ys
andX (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x,y] : andX xs ys
```

So now we have list of lists, and each sublist contains an element from the first list, and one from the second list. A problem however is that the second and third clause use `xs` and `ys` as output. We can not do this, since we expect a list of lists. We can solve this by rewriting it to:

```
andX :: [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
andX []     []     = []  
andX (x:xs) []     = [x] : andX xs []
andX []     (y:ys) = [y] : andX [] ys
andX (x:xs) (y:ys) = [x,y] : andX xs ys
```

**Example**:

```
Prelude> andX [1,4,2,5] [1,3,0,2,5]
[[1,1],[4,3],[2,0],[5,2],[5]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was incredibly informative and Ive learned a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain this code:

```
andX :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
andX []         []      = []  
andX xs         []      = xs
andX []         ys      = ys
andX (x:xs) (y:ys)      = x : y : andX xs ys
```

For example, and looking your answer, you want this:

```
andX [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
=> [1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

or

```
andX [1,4,2,5] [1,3,0,2,5,7]
=> [1,1,4,3,2,0,5,2,5,7]
```

Look at your attempt (it was close enough)

```
andX :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
andX []         []      = []  
andX [xs]       []      = [xs]  
andX []         [ys]    = [ys]
```

Here, the first three cases are ok, but be carefull `[xs]` and `[ys]` are lists with just one element, so you will get in a patter matching failure if the lists has different sizes.

```
andX [x:xs] [y:ys]  = [x,y] : andX [xs] [ys]
```

here is the best problem, first `[x:xs] :: [[a]]` that's a list of list, you have to use `()` when you are doing pattern matching.
 Then `[x,y] : andX [xs] [ys]` is wrong, again, types doesn't match, you are trying to add `[a]` into a `[a]`, and you have just to add the `a` element, you do it like `x : y : andX [xs] [ys]` if you read it is "add element x, add element y and then put the rest of the list `andX [xs] [ys]`"

Comment: This will still error if the difference between the lists is more than one element.

Comment: `andX [1,4,2,5] [1,3,0,2,5,7]`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `[x:xs]` to `(x:xs)`, and the same for and `[y:ys]`.

Also, you can't prepend a list to a list; you prepend elements to a list. So change `[x, y]:` to `x:y:`.

You don't want to create nested lists for cases 2 and 3, either, so change `[xs]` to just `xs`, and the same for `[ys]`